# Set Secondary Tile BackgroundImage from Image in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This is how I get the stream from an image url:

```
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            response = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(IMAGEURL_HERE, UriKind.Absolute));
        }

        SaveImage(response);
```

And this is how I save it to IsoloatedStorage:

```
    private void SaveImage(Stream result)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(result);
            var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = file.CreateFile("FILENAME.jpg"))
            {
                int width = wb.PixelWidth;
                int height = wb.PixelHeight;
                if (wb.PixelWidth > 336)
                {
                    width = 336;
                }
                if (wb.PixelHeight > 336)
                {
                    height = 336;
                }
                Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, width, height, 0, 100);
            }
        }
    }
```

So let's say the file is FILENAME.jpg, I thought I could set it as BackgroundImage to a Secondary Tile like this:

```
var tileData = new FlipTileData()
{
...
BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/FILENAME.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
...
```

It won't work. It throws no exception, only the image won't be displayed. What do I miss? Of course if I put the Image Url as Uri to BackgroundImage it works, but this is not what I want.

Edit: And I have seen similar questions here but it did not help me with my code.

Comment: tileData.BackgroundImage = ...

Comment: I've edited the code. Down there, it's the FlipTileData ctor, so creating the Tile is not the problem, it works great, also works great with Image URL from a site, but not from IsoStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. May be its help.

```
string imageFolder = @"\Shared\ShellContent"; 
string shareJPEG = "FILENAME.jpg";

private void SaveImage(Stream result)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if(!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
        }

        if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(shareJPEG))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(shareJPEG);
        }

        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imageFolder, shareJPEG);
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(filePath);
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(result);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

        // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream. 
        int width = wb.PixelWidth;
        int height = wb.PixelHeight;
        if (wb.PixelWidth > 336)
        {
            width = 336;
        }
        if (wb.PixelHeight > 336)
        {
            height = 336;
        }
        Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, width, height, 0, 100);

        fileStream.Close();


    }
} 

private void CreateTile()
{
    var tileData = new FlipTileData()
    {
         ....
         string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(imageFolder, shareJPEG);                
         BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:" + filePath, UriKind.Absolute);
         ....
    } 
}
```

Comment: The FlipTileData() throws System.UriFormatException. I've checked the path with FileExists before creating the Tile, the file is there. Any idea?

Comment: Check my updated answer. Now its working perfect for me. There is missing `:` in uri.