# How to set text in the middle of secondary tile WP 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, tiles

I am trying to create a secondary tile that will display a string in it. I am building the app for windows phone 8.1. I have the following code for the tile but I would like the text in the center of the app:

```
SecondaryTile("TestTile",
               numDays + " days",
               tileActivationArguments,
               blankPic,
               TileSize.Square150x150);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or to build an image from the text to display?

Solution:
XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="TextGrid" Width="150" Height="150" Background="Red">
    <TextBlock x:Name="numDay" FontSize="36" />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
NumDay.Text = numDays + " days"
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(TextGrid);
```

I used this code to create my image and then set it as background picture in SecondaryTile.

Comment: If you want any more control over the content, then you need to render image and use it for tile.

Comment: Can you point me to a direction of how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107640/set-secondary-tile-backgroundimage-from-image-in-isolated-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating custom tile with image is rougly done in these steps:

1) Render your image. `WriteableBitmap` class can render `UIElement` you pass to it:

```
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(300, 300);

            wb.Render(myGrid);

            wb.Invalidate();
```

So you need to construct your tile from UI elements like container + controls. In your case it would be for example `Grid` (with max width) and aligned `TextBlocks`

2) Once you have this image, save it as PNG (for better quality) into folder

> "isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/"

otherwise your tile cannot access it.

3) Now all you need to do is create `StandardTileData` and set BackgroundImage to your newly created image.

You can also download and use **IsoStoreSpy** while debugging. It can show you your phone's internal storage. So you can see whether and how the image been rendered.

Comment: wb.Render wasn't valid for wp 8.1 But this pointed me to the right direction. I used `RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(grid)` Thanks @Filip